# Check if mouse is over a rotated sprite? C++

Tags: c++, math

I'm making a game in c++. It is a card game. I have made 13 cards that rotate about a point to arc out to make your hand. I need a way to figure out which card the user clicks on. My cards are basically rectangles rotated about a point that is in the center of the cards. I was thinking of maybe getting the mouse point and rotating it about  my central point but i'm not sure how to rotate a point about a point. Thanks.

Comment: How exactly are you able to rotate an entire rectangle without being able to rotate a single point?

Comment: By using Allegro's pivot sprite function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Rotating a around p

The trick is to reduce rotating around a point to rotating around the origin by doing translations.

1. Subtract p from a (move to the origin)
2. [Rotate by angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics))
3. Add p to resulting point (move again)

Formula for rotating (x, y) aroung the origin:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If (*x*<sub>0</sub>, *y*<sub>0</sub>) is the central point and (*x*<sub>m</sub>, *y*<sub>m</sub>) is where the mouse is, you could calculate the angle of the mouse with respect to the center point by translating (*x*<sub>0</sub>, *y*<sub>0</sub>) to the origin (0, 0) and then converting to polar coordinates.

1. Translate to origin:

   (*x*', *y*') = (*x*<sub>m</sub> - *x*<sub>0</sub>, *y*<sub>m</sub> - *y*<sub>0</sub>)
2. Convert from rectangular to polar (*x*, *y*) → (*r*, *θ*):

   *r* = sqrt(*x*'<sup>2</sup> + *y*'<sup>2</sup>)
   *θ* = tan<sup>-1</sup>(*y*' / *x*')

The angle *θ* should be enough to tell you which card is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You've gotten a couple of possibilities already. This is a rather different one that depends more on programming and less on trig.

The idea would be to draw each card in a unique, solid, color in a back buffer. Check the color at the point that matches the mouse click, and you have the card. At one time this would have been grossly impractical -- but with modern graphics hardware this can be quite competitive.

Answer (score 0):

You could check that point is a part of polygon. [Here](http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html#The%20C%20Code) you could find pretty fast implementation.